# Angular 11.0.3 Can't bind to DIRECTIVE since it isn't a known property of element

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I generated new @Directive by Angular CLI, it was imported it to my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { DatosEnMemoriaService } from './datos-en-memoria.service';
import { ClonarDirective } from './investigaciones/marta/clonar.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClonarDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(DatosEnMemoriaService, {
      passThruUnknownUrl: true, post204: false, put204: false
  })
  ],  
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and I try to use in mycomponent.html

```
<li *appClonar="3">
  <button (click)="this.router.navigateByUrl('/gesprodes');"  >
    Gesprodes
    <span>Inicia a aplicación de gesprodes</span>
  </button>
</li>
```

The directive.ts:

```
import { Directive,Input,TemplateRef,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
 
@Directive({
  selector: '[appClonar]'
})
export class ClonarDirective {
 
  constructor(private tp:TemplateRef<any>,
              private vcr:ViewContainerRef) { }
 
    @Input() appClonar:number;
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tp);
 
    console.log(this.appClonar);
    for(let i = 0; i<this.appClonar ;i++){
          this.vcr.createEmbeddedView(this.tp);
        }
  }
}
```

I got the error:

core.js:9813 NG0303: Can't bind to 'appClonar' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.

I tried almost every possible changes, following this angular docs everything should work but it does not.

My version angular: 11.0.3
My version node: 12.0.0

Any help

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this

```
<li [appClonar] >
</li>
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing. Clonar is a structural directive and needs to be used with `*appClonar`.